# Intricacies on DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

Why is this odd behaviour ?

I want to create this date **2009-02-15** to my specified format, but it shows a year of **1970** . Why is this happening ? I found this example on PHP.net manual.

```
<?php
$format = 'Y-m-!d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n"; //Output is Format: Y-m-!d H:i:s; 1970-01-15 15:16:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the `!`.  From the manual for [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> If format contains the character `!`, then portions of the generated time not provided in format, as well as values to the left-hand side of the `!`, will be set to corresponding values from the Unix epoch.

This means that anything left of the `!` will be set to `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. In your case (`Y-m-!d H:i:s`) that means that the year and month will be set to January 1970, while the remaining parts of the date will be set according to your string.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it `!` sign in precise format? It should not be there. Correct format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, so:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
```

-see [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), it explains meaning of `!` (and you need not have it in precise format)

Answer (score 1):

*Check It*

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2009-02-15 15:16:17'));
echo $date;
```